# What is wrong with my thinking, simple groups order $168$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> How many elements of order $7$ are there in a simple group of order $168$?

I will work on this more but I have seen some solutions out there. My only question is regarding what is wrong what my thinking here:

An element of order $7$ produces a cyclic group of order $7$ which is abelian and thus would be normal in $G$ and $G$ is simple so the only normal subgroups are itself $G$ and the trivial subgroup $\{e\}$ but the cyclic group is neither of those so there couldn't be an element of order $7$?

Comment: Abelian subgroups are not necessarily normal. Normal: $gH=Hg$ for $g \in G$. Abelian $gh=hg$ for $g,h \in H$.

Comment: All right thank you. I will try to find a counterexample to put in my notes, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem with your reasoning is that abelian subgroup and normal subgroup are different concepts with similar definitions.

A subgroup $H \leq G$ is abelian if $gh=hg$ for every $g,h \in H$. It has nothing to do with $G$.

A subgroup $H \leq G$ is normal if $gH=Hg$ for every $g \in G$. It has $g$ coming from $G$, not just form $H$. Sometimes I like to write the condition $H = g^{-1}Hg$.

For example:

Let $G= \{ (), (12), (23), (13), (123), (132) \}$ be the symmetric group of degree 3. Then $H=\{ (), (12) \}$ is an abelian subgroup because $() \cdot () = () \cdot ()$, $() \cdot (12) = (12) \cdot ()$, and $(12) \cdot (12) = (12) \cdot (12)$.  However $H$ is not normal, since $(23)^{-1} H (23) = \{ (), (13) \} \neq H$.

You know something must be wrong, because [Cauchy's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory)) claims that if $7$ divides $|G|$ (and it does when $|G|=168=7\cdot24$), then $G$ has at least one element of order $7$.

Comment: Thank you, ironically I was just typing up a "solution" where I use $S_3$ and the cyclic subgroup generated by $(12)$ to show that that subgroup is indeed not normal in $S_3$. ;)

Comment: I'll upvote if you post it :-)

Comment: (The knights of the Crusade of Answers would come after me if this question had no official answer posted, but just my comments, so I had to post something. :-)

Comment: We can't have that happen, @Jack ! (+1)